# Gradient of a velocity vector

Tags: vectors, tangent-line, slope

Apologies if this is extremely simple. I'm a biology undergrad and I need this to measure cell membranes but I'm really struggling to find a solution anywhere.

I'm trying to find the gradient of a tangent line given a tangent vector $(a, b)$ so that I can plot the tangent line. I think I therefore have the $x$ and $y$ components of a velocity vector. How would I find the gradient of the velocity vector to plot this in the form $y=mx+c$ ?

Comment: Do you want the line $y=mx+c$ to be tangent to the membrane at the point where you found your tangent vector? "Gradient of a velocity vector" could mean something else to someone else.

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't mean to cause confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the tangent vector is $(a,b)$ where $a$ is the $x$ component and $b$ is the $y$ component, that means the vector "rises" $b$ units in the $y$ direction while "running" $a$ units in the $x$ direction.
(Negative numbers reverse the direction, so for example $b=-2$ means you fall $2$ units and $a=-3$ means you travel $3$ units to the left.)

The ratio of rise/run is exactly what $m$ represents in $y=mx+c.$
So you want something of the form

$$ y = \frac ba x + c.$$

You now need to set $c$ so that your line passes through the tangent point.
Set $x$ and $y$ to their values at the tangent point,
solve the equation for $c,$ and that will be the value of $c$ you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! This might be outside of the scope of this forum but I actually tried this and it doesn't give me what I want - is it possible that I have something slightly different to a tangent vector to start with? I'm finding _(a, b)_ from a catmull rom curve which works when I plot using plt.quiver but not when I use the method you described? Would maybe having a standard unit vector alter this?

Comment: It takes more than two numbers to describe a Catmull-Rom spline, so I'm not sure what $a$ and $b$ are. If they make a vector to the next control point, then $(a,b)$ could be close to a tangent but usually would be different enough for you to notice.

Comment: Thank you for you help and patience. It might be that, I'll keep searching.